how to turn data table in shiny from vertical to horzintal placed?
enter image description here
output$table2<- renderTable(asdf_lm$fitted)
How do I flip this table? It is the second one in the picture, with the single column.
Trying to get a single row. So that the data fits on the screen better.

Assuming that I correctly understand your question (please post a minimal reproducible example next time), you can just use t() to transpose the data you're trying to display.
It seems that you want to display the fitted data from a lm() model fit.
Here is an example with mtcars dataset:
library(shiny)

if (interactive()) {
  shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
      fluidRow(
        column(12,
          tableOutput('table')
        )
      )
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {
        output$table <- renderTable({
            mod <- lm(mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars)

            # Here you transpose your data.
            t(mod$fitted)
        })
    }
  )
  }

Result:

